# Aurelia href.bind is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, routes, aurelia

**My route:**

```
{ route: 'weather/:woeid', href: '#/weather',  name: 'weatherd', moduleId: 'weatherd', nav: true, title: 'Weather' }
```

**My HTML:**

```
<a href.bind="route: weatherd, params.bind: { woeid: cityId }">
```

I want to build this url

```
#/weather/23423
```

I am having very hard time doing this. There is nothing in their documentation.
Anybody please help

Comment: I don't know _anything_ about [tag:aurelia], but you seem to build a link with a "route" called `weatherd`, but that's the name of the `moduleId` you use, the `route` is called `weather`. Is that intended?

Comment: That weatherd thing is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use route-href instead of href.bind in this case.

```
<a route-href="route: weatherd, params.bind: { woeid: cityId }">
```

You would use href.bind like this:

```
<a href.bind="'weather/' + cityId" >
```

This can be found in the "Generating Route URLs" subsection of the Routing section in the cheat sheet [here](http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/cheat-sheet#routing)

Answer (score 1):

`<a href.bind="route: weatherd, params.bind: { woeid: cityId }">`

should be

`<a route-href="route: weatherd; params.bind: { woeid: cityId }">`

Use route-href, and use a semicolon instead of a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `,` by `;` :

`<a
  route-href="route: weatherd; params.bind: { woeid: cityId }"></a>`